# jqueryUI multi handle and image as handle slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I am trying to make a jqueryUI slider where multiple images can be used as the handle.

http://jsfiddle.net/trivender/6NftK/7/

I need some help:

1. The top visible handle should slide first.
2. As soon as I slide any of the two sliders the initial value of the other slider gets set in its  box. I want that the value is only set when the user slides the corresponding slider.

This is my javascript

```
$(function () {
    $("#sliderPointer").slider({ min: 0, max: 100, values: [50, 50]});

    $("#sliderImage").slider({ min: 0, max: 100, values: [50, 50],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#one").val(ui.values[0]);
            $("#two").val(ui.values[1]);
            $("#sliderPointer").slider("option", "values"
                                         , [ui.values[0], ui.values[1]]);
            for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; i++) {
                $("#pointer" + (i + 1)).text(ui.values[i]);
            }
        }
    });

    var indexPointer = 1;
    $("#sliderPointer a").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('id', 'pointer' + indexPointer);
        indexPointer++;
    });
    var indexImage = 1;
    $("#sliderImage a").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('id', 'image' + indexImage);
        indexImage++;
    });

    var i = 1;
    var $logos = $("img");
    $logos.each(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        $("#image" + i).css("background", "url(" + src + ")");
        i++;
    });
});
```

Comment: I do not understand this part `As soon as I slide any of the two sliders the initial value of the other slider gets set in its box.`
What do you mean by the other slider gets set in its box?
`I want that the value is only set when the user slides the corresponding slider.` This seems to working already. If i move the slider A (153.jpg) then the value is written into the textbox `<input id="one" type="text">` If i move slider B (901.jpg) the value is written into the other textbox. It seems to me your fiddle is already doing what i think you want it to do. Could you clarify what is missing?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this:).When I move slider A(153.jpg) then the value of slider B also gets set . I want that the value of slider B should set when I move slider B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Hmm..  Does this work for you?

jQuery

```
$("#sliderImage").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    values: [50, 50],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("table").find('input').eq($(ui.handle).attr('id').substring(5)-1).val(ui.values[$(ui.handle).attr('id').substring(5)-1]);
        $("#sliderPointer").slider("option", "values", [ui.values[0], ui.values[1]]);
        $("#pointer" + ($(ui.handle).attr('id').substring(5))).text(ui.values[$(ui.handle).attr('id').substring(5)-1]);
    }
});
```

CSS

```
#image1 {
    z-index:300;
}
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/c934g/9/

Comment: I did not see the difference. Could you help me to see it?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree Sorry I just updated it.. Basically he wants the numbers to be uninitialized until that particular image has been dragged.  So image 2 Number should be blank until its dragged.. I also changed the z-index so that the top image would always be grabbed if the two images were on top of each other.  Got to run hopefully that makes sense if not i'll check back later.

Comment: @Trevor, Thanks a lot. That's what I exactly wanted right now. I am very happy with your response that is even quicker then jqueryui forums. I will keep coming back:). Just to let you know that the number of images(logos) in html will be  variable . I need to make a handle for each logo. Please share your suggestions.

Comment: @Triven Here is another example for you that would be able to handle a number of images..  http://jsfiddle.net/5XhAJ/  After experimenting with it for a while I found that the z-index does help especially initially.  All the sliders will move how would expect.  The top one first.. However later on Jquery ui has a feature where if you drag a slider to another slider the the last one dragged will be moved first.. Even if its behind the other.. Now there may be a work around but its pretty intuitive anyway..  See if this example works for you.

Comment: Wonderful!!..I think we can change jquery(line 20) from $("#sliderPointer").slider("option", "values", [ui.values[0], ui.values[1], ui.values[2]]); to $("#sliderPointer").slider("option", "values", imgValues); . What do you say!!:)

Comment: @Trevor, I made some changes and improvements in the slider. Now I want that the image(handle) clicked by user should slide on top of all other images(handle). I think we can set  a highest index to the selected image(handle). Please share your suggestions/help:) http://jsfiddle.net/trivender/6NftK/19/

Comment: @Triven your right about the `line 20` change I forgot about that one.  Nice!  Yeah I'll look into it to see if I can come up with anything..  Though It might be as late as tomorrow until I get a good chance to look at it.  Maybe you'll find a solution in the meantime, but I'll get back to you once I look into it.  Thanks

Comment: @Trevor, Its done.. :) http://biinfotech.com/confirmit/jqueryplugin/imgslider/demo.html .You really helped me a lot..Feel free if need any help anytime.